# Saltstack - File Searialization - Keep Empty lines, File content sequence and Comments intact

Tags: serialization, salt-stack, filebeat

I am trying to use salt file serialization, but it is removing all empty lines, sorting the complete file in alphabetical order and removing all comments. I dont want these to happen.
Tried to check [here](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.serialize) and [here](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation), but could not find anything.

```
{% import_yaml "app-filebeat.yml" as config %}

manage_file:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml
    - source: salt://filebeat.yml.tmpl
    - template: jinja

conf_file:
  file.serialize:
    - name: /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml
    - dataset: {{ config }}
    - formatter: yaml
    - merge_if_exists: true
```

app_filebeat.yml:

```
output.logstash:
  hosts: ['myhost.example.com:5158']
```

filebeat.yml.tmpl:

```
# Filebeat prospector configuration
filebeat:
  config:
    inputs:
      enabled: true
      path: /opt/filebeat/prospector-conf/*.yml
      reload.enabled: true
      reload.period: 300s

# Logstash configuration
output.logstash:
  hosts:
  worker: 1
  compression_level: 3
  loadbalance: true
  ssl:
    certificate: /usr/share/filebeat/file_beat.crt
    key: /usr/share/filebeat/file_beat.key
    verification_mode: none

# Filebeat Logging Configuration
logging:
  level: debug
  to_files: true
  files:
    path: /var/tellme/log/filebeat/
    name: filebeat.log
    rotateeverybytes: 10485760
    keepfiles: 7
```

Ouput:

```
filebeat:
  config:
    inputs:
      enabled: true
      path: /opt/filebeat/prospector-conf/*.yml
      reload.enabled: true
      reload.period: 300s
logging:
  files:
    keepfiles: 7
    name: filebeat.log
    path: /var/tellme/log/filebeat/
    rotateeverybytes: 10485760
  level: debug
  to_files: true
output.logstash:
  compression_level: 3
  hosts:
  - myhost.example.com:5158
  loadbalance: true
  ssl:
    certificate: /usr/share/filebeat/file_beat.crt
    key: /usr/share/filebeat/file_beat.key
    verification_mode: none
  worker: 1
```

Salt State output:

```
----------
          ID: manage_file
    Function: file.managed
        Name: /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml
      Result: True
     Comment: File /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml updated
     Started: 04:53:53.678745
    Duration: 118.489 ms
     Changes:
              ----------
              diff:
                  ---
                  +++
                  @@ -0,0 +1,29 @@
                  +# Filebeat prospector configuration
                  +filebeat:
                  +  config:
                  +    inputs:
                  +      enabled: true
                  +      path: /opt/filebeat/prospector-conf/*.yml
                  +      reload.enabled: true
                  +      reload.period: 300s
                  +
                  +# Logstash configuration
                  +output.logstash:
                  +  hosts:
                  +  worker: 1
                  +  compression_level: 3
                  +  loadbalance: true
                  +  ssl:
                  +    certificate: /usr/share/filebeat/file_beat.crt
                  +    key: /usr/share/filebeat/file_beat.key
                  +    verification_mode: none
                  +
                  +# Filebeat Logging Configuration
                  +logging:
                  +  level: debug
                  +  to_files: true
                  +  files:
                  +    path: /var/tellme/log/filebeat/
                  +    name: filebeat.log
                  +    rotateeverybytes: 10485760
                  +    keepfiles: 7
----------
          ID: conf_file
    Function: file.serialize
        Name: /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml
      Result: True
     Comment: File /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml updated
     Started: 04:53:53.797737
    Duration: 14.986 ms
     Changes:
              ----------
              diff:
                  ---
                  +++
                  @@ -1,4 +1,3 @@
                  -# Filebeat prospector configuration
                   filebeat:
                     config:
                       inputs:
                  @@ -6,24 +5,21 @@
                         path: /opt/filebeat/prospector-conf/*.yml
                         reload.enabled: true
                         reload.period: 300s
                  -
                  -# Logstash configuration
                  +logging:
                  +  files:
                  +    keepfiles: 7
                  +    name: filebeat.log
                  +    path: /var/tellme/log/filebeat/
                  +    rotateeverybytes: 10485760
                  +  level: debug
                  +  to_files: true
                   output.logstash:
                  -  hosts:
                  -  worker: 1
                     compression_level: 3
                  +  hosts:
                  +  - myhost.example.com:5158
                     loadbalance: true
                     ssl:
                       certificate: /usr/share/filebeat/file_beat.crt
                       key: /usr/share/filebeat/file_beat.key
                       verification_mode: none
                  -
                  -# Filebeat Logging Configuration
                  -logging:
                  -  level: debug
                  -  to_files: true
                  -  files:
                  -    path: /var/tellme/log/filebeat/
                  -    name: filebeat.log
                  -    rotateeverybytes: 10485760
                  -    keepfiles: 7
                  +  worker: 1
```

Please help.

Comment: Only the `hosts` section seems to have additional value extra in rendered output. Looking at this, its hard to say what is the expected output? What is in `app-filebeat.yml`?

Comment: @seshadri_c: I have edited the query with the content.

Answer (score 2):

The `file.serialize` module does not look like the right choice for this requirement.

You already have a template for `filebeat.yml`, and the requirement is to modify this file in-place and update only hosts under `output.logstash:` section.

For this the `file.accumulated` might be better with changes as below:

**filebeat.yml.tmpl**:

```
# Logstash configuration
output.logstash:
  hosts:
  {%- for host in accumulator['extra_config'] %}
    - {{ host }}
  {%- endfor %}
```

**app-filebeat.yml**:

```
hosts: ['myhost.example.com:5158']
```

Then the below states:

```yaml
{% import_yaml "app-filebeat.yml" as config %}

extra_config:
 file.accumulated:
    - filename: /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml
    - text: {{ config.hosts }}
    - require_in:
        - file: manage_file

manage_file:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml
    - source: salt://filebeat.yml.tmpl
    - template: jinja
```

Comment: I am using file.serialize because my requirement is to override any value in the template. Replacing the host is just a small example that I took. Correct requirement is to override any key in the yaml hierarchy. Also I should be able to add new keys on the fly while overriding.

Comment: May be you can update the question with this requirement so its more obvious. Also, the template are meant to have many such conditions/loops to dynamically update configuration on-the-fly.

Comment: Serialize actually works perfect, but it removes the comments and empty lines as well as it is sorting the yaml keys in alphabetical order. Sorting is not an issue, but I would like to keep the comments and empty lines for better readability. :(

Comment: but that is the point. `file.serialize` will not keep comments. nor any kind of presentation data. it is a serialization component not a text editor. it takes machine data and translates it into other machine language. the comments and presentation data is lost before it even gets to file.serialize. importing the yaml into a data structure removes them because it is a data structure not a text structure.

Answer (score 0):

`import_yaml` and `merge_if_exists` load YAML as a python data structure. All formatting, ordering, and comments are lost. This is intentional, because they are irrelevant to the data structure.

If you want to manage the file as a plain text file, then use `file.managed`. If you want to manage it as structured data, then you don't get to choose the presentation details. Don't try to do both to the same file.

Comment: I can see Serializer doing that from the output. If you see my code "import_yaml" is just importing a yaml file having 2 lines, it does not have any comment